# Copy an Array and delete doubles

Tags: python

I got this code

```html
A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
B = [0 for b in range(16)]
skipped = 0
for i in range(16):
 if  A[i] == A[i-1]:
     skipped += 1
 else:
    B[i-skipped] = A[i]

print(B)
```

**The output:**

```html
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

it eliminates the doubles. But if i got an array where doubles are at more random index it fails, like:

**The Array#2:**

```html
A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 7, 8, 8, 9]
```

**The output#2**

```html
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

In the output#2 there is the value 2 at index 1 and index 5, but i just want to eliminate all the doubles.

**Sum:**
So basically my algorithm should copy the values from Array A to Array B and eliminate all doubles independent from their index.

**EDIT:** i have to put it in pseudocode so i cant use convert methods or functions like SET

Comment: Can't we use set() method to convert it to set so that we can delete duplicates??

Comment: "i have to put it in pseudocode so i cant use convert methods or functions like SET" - Pseudocode can use those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set` to do it:

```py
A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
B = set(A)
print(B)
```

This code returns a set. To convert set to list you can write `some_list = list(B)`.

Another way to do what you need:

```py
A = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]
B = []
for x in A:
    if x not in B:
      B.append(x)
print(B)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i have to use like simple code to put into pseudocode no converting. I will edit my question, this is not clear

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: well that seems easy.. x is like an Iterator thorugh the array? it works! thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right.